# Add an item in a modal and update select

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a `View` that contains a form. The form has a select field that I populate with an AJAX call depending on previous choices. Next to the field I have an `Add` button that opens up a `modal` that contains a `Partial view` for the object that needs to be added.

This is pretty much where I get lost. If I click the `Add` button, I get redirected to a page with only the partial view in it.

If the call is successful, I want to call a function, I set the `OnSuccess` parameter in the `AjaxOptions` but that function takes some parameters. I wrote a workaround in case the parameters are null, but is there a way to call wthe function with the parameters in it?

This is the `div` that holds the `select` and the `button`

```
<div class="form-group" id="divItem">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-target="#itemModal" data-toggle="modal" type="button" id="itemModalButton">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        &nbsp;@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title, new {@class = "control-label"})
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="itemField">
        <script id="itemTemplate" type="text/template">
            <select class="form-control" id="ItemId" {{^.}}disabled{{/.}}>
                {{#.}}
                <option value="{{Id}}">{{Title}} - {{Description}}</option>
                {{/.}}
            </select>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Modal is quite simple:

```
<div class="fade modal" id="itemModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="itemModalBody">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I load the `Partial view` depending on the selection of a previous select:

```
$itemModalButton.click(function() {
    $itemModalBody.load("/Api/Item/New/" + $topItem.val());
});
```

The partial view:

```
@model Item
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("New", "Item", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "getItems"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TopItemId)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>New item</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tite, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Create"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")   
}
```

And the `POST` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Novo([Bind(Include = "TopItemId,Title,Description")] Item model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    _db.Items.Add(item);     
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(await _db.Items.Where(x => x.TopItemId == model.TopItemId).ToListAsync());
}
```

That's pretty much all the code. I know I'm missing something and also I know I'm doing something wrong, but on idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I did stuff a bid different, and Tieson T. helped a lot (thanks :) )

To start with the partial view, everything is the same, except for the `using` statement:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id = "partialViewForm"}))
```

I render the view when the page loads, so the HTML for the modal now looks like this:

```
<div class="fade modal" id="itemModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{
                    Html.RenderAction("New", "Item");
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And because the HTML is already rendered, I don't need to sent the `TopItemId` to the controller, I only need to set it to the hidden field when the `Add` button is clicked. So the `javascript` for that looks like this:

```
$itemModalButton.click(function() {
    $("#partialViewForm").find("#TopItemId").val($topItem.val());
});
```

And I post the form like this:

```
$partialViewForm.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($partialViewForm);
    if ($partialViewForm.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Novo", "Subkonto")',
            data: $partialViewForm.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                // handle the result    
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // handle the error
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what your markup looks like, I'm just guessing, but it sounds like either a form is getting submitted, or a hyperlink is being activated when you do this:

```
$itemModalButton.click(function() {
    $itemModalBody.load("/Api/Item/New/" + $topItem.val());
});
```

To fix it, add the event argument, and then use it to cancel the button's default behavior:

```
$itemModalButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $itemModalBody.load("/Api/Item/New/" + $topItem.val());
});
```

Comment: That button just opens the modal and that works fine, it doesn't post the form. When I press the `Create` button inside the modal, it redirects me to a page with only the partial view, it doesn't refresh the modal with the errors

Comment: Then it sounds like _that_ form is submitting the page. You likely need to capture the submit event of that form and handle it yourself. I'm relatively certain that the Unobtrusive Ajax library only works with content that was present at DOM-ready. Would have to look, though.

Comment: Another thing is that I can't render the scripts section because partial views don't have access to the sections...

Comment: You place whatever scripts the dynamic content needs in the parent view, and the attempt your bindings after successfully loading your remote content. So, if the modal content needs Unobtrusive Ajax, you load it in the parent view. I'm not sure how you apply the bindings it uses after the fact, though; it may be easier to simply use jQuery and write your own. I could update this answer if you need an example of how to do that.

Comment: jQuery and AJAX aint my strong suite so any help would be awesome

Comment: From looking at the [source of the current version](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js), loading the Unobtrusive library in the parent view should be enough. The bindings are applied at the document level, so your modal content should still be handled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97131/discussion-between-gregoryhousemd-and-tieson-t).

Comment: I made a couple of changes and now the situation is completely different, but you helped a lot and it works now :)

Comment: If it's something you think someone else would benefit from knowing, amend your question to cover the question your current solution solves, and then post your own answer.